# Android P2P connection with CC3100

Tags: android, tcpclient, tcp

I'm using a network microcontroller, CC3100 on MSP430FF5529

I'm trying to send data to the board from my android device.
The program of the microcontroller is a sample p2p application developed from Texas instruments. It should be able to receive data. It open a TCP server socket and wait until connection

I developed an android application base on this tutorial [Android TCP Connection Tutorial](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/20/android-tcp-connection-tutorial/)  only the TCP client parts. 
But it doesn't connect properly.
this is the function when the cc3100 open the server; I placed some CLIwrite to see the progress on tera term ( a terminal/console ).

```
static _i32 BsdTcpServer(_u16 Port){

    SlSockAddrIn_t  Addr;

    SlSockAddrIn_t  LocalAddr;

_u16          idx = 0;
_u16          AddrSize = 0;
_i16          SockID = 0;
_i32          Status = 0;
_i16          newSockID = 0;
_u16          LoopCount = 0;
_u16          recvSize = 0;
CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] var declared \n\r");

for (idx=0 ; idx<BUF_SIZE ; idx++)
{
    uBuf.BsdBuf[idx] = (_u8)(idx % 10);
}
CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] exit: for (idx=0 ; idx<BUF_SIZE ; idx++) \n\r");
LocalAddr.sin_family = SL_AF_INET;
LocalAddr.sin_port = sl_Htons((_u16)Port);
LocalAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;

SockID = sl_Socket(SL_AF_INET,SL_SOCK_STREAM, 0);
CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] sl_Socket \n\r");
if( SockID < 0 )
{
    CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] sockID < 0 \n\r");
    CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] Create socket Error \n\r");
    ASSERT_ON_ERROR(SockID);
}
CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] Socket created \n\r");
AddrSize = sizeof(SlSockAddrIn_t);
Status = sl_Bind(SockID, (SlSockAddr_t *)&LocalAddr, AddrSize);
if( Status < 0 )
{
    CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] status2 < 0 \n\r");
    sl_Close(SockID);
    CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] Socket address assignment Error \n\r");
    ASSERT_ON_ERROR(Status);
}
CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] socket adress ok \n\r");

Status = sl_Listen(SockID, 0);
CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] sl listen \n\r");
if( Status < 0 )
{
    CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] status1 < 0 \n\r");
    sl_Close(SockID);
    CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] Listen Error \n\r");
    ASSERT_ON_ERROR(Status);
}
CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] status > 0 \n\r");newSockID = sl_Accept(SockID, ( struct SlSockAddr_t *)&Addr,(SlSocklen_t*)&AddrSize); if( newSockID < 0 )
{
   CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] newsockID < 0 \n\r");
    sl_Close(SockID);
    CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] Accept connection Error \n\r");
    ASSERT_ON_ERROR(newSockID);
}

while (LoopCount < NO_OF_PACKETS)
{
    recvSize = BUF_SIZE;

    do
    {
        Status = sl_Recv(newSockID, &uBuf.BsdBuf[BUF_SIZE - recvSize], recvSize, 0);
        if( Status <= 0 )
        {
            CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] status < 0 \n\r");
            sl_Close(newSockID);
            sl_Close(SockID);
            CLI_Write(" [TCP Server] Data recv Error \n\r");
            ASSERT_ON_ERROR(TCP_RECV_ERROR);
        }

        recvSize -= Status;

    }while(recvSize > 0);

    LoopCount++;
}

Status = sl_Close(newSockID);
ASSERT_ON_ERROR(Status);

Status = sl_Close(SockID);
ASSERT_ON_ERROR(Status);
CLI_Write(" return function \n\r");
return SUCCESS;}
```

When I try to send a string, it doesnt work and it is blocked at this ligne

```
        Status = sl_Recv(newSockID, &uBuf.BsdBuf[BUF_SIZE - recvSize], recvSize, 0);
```

the application on the exemple should connect at the card IP at the right PORT, but when I try to send something it doesn't send anything.
I downloaded the application TCPclient, and it sends message but on the console I don't see the TCP connection established.

Using Iperf i can check the connection between my android device and the board, and it works correctly.

someone any suggestion?